# Why Safari sends Origin header on redirect?

Tags: nginx, jsf, safari, reverse-proxy

I'm developing a web application with JSF2.2, and using protected view for CSRF protection.
I use Nginx as a reverse proxy server.

The problem I'm facing is, when I perform a GET request as a result of redirect which is a response to a POST request ([PRG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get)), the following error occurs.
This doesn't happen when I use Chrome, Firefox or Edge.

```
2020-03-02 16:30:33,623 SEVERE [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.lifecycle] (default task-377) JSF1100: Origin [sic] header value https://example.com does not appear to be a protected view. Preventing display of viewId /some/protected/view.xhtml
2020-03-02 16:30:33,624 ERROR [my.project.commons.exception.logger.ExceptionLogFormatterImpl] (default task-377) SessionId=ZH1NL8D53vR6FLfG5hj4v3fNp3OVCByXBrzZJtGy RequestId=WNsDVWCm ContractNo=64811790 CSRFトークンエラー: javax.faces.application.ProtectedViewException: JSF1100: Origin [sic] header value https://example.com does not appear to be a protected view. Preventing display of viewId /some/protected/view.xhtml
```

This is because:

- On [RestoreViewPhase](https://github.com/javaserverfaces/mojarra/blob/master/impl/src/main/java/com/sun/faces/lifecycle/RestoreViewPhase.java), JSF checks if Origin is valid, and that fails.
  (because JSF checks Origin's host, port and **path** while Origin doesn't have path. this looks like a bug to me..)
- Safari sends Origin header on redirect. While Chrome, Firefox and Edge doesn't.

So the question is, why Safari sends Origin header on redirect?
Seeing [specification](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#origin-header), Origin header won't be set on GET request if it is not a CORS request, indeed, Safari doesn't send Origin on regular GET requests(not redirect).

Or, is this related to the reverse proxy? Does it possibly make internal redirect something like a CORS request?

This can be reproduced with Safari 10.1.2 on Mac OS X 10.10.5 and Safari 12.1.1 on iPad and **not** with Safari 13.0.4 on Mac OS X 10.15.2

Comment: 1: you cannot have  a redirect in a POST. You cannot have a redirect send by a browser. You can have a redirect send by the server as result of a POST send by the client.2:If you are sure JSF is playing a role in causing this problem and not just ypu using it, creats a [mcve], post version info and implementation 3:Reverse proxy related? Try without. 4:Your last sentence contains contradictions.

Comment: @Kukeltje Thanks for your comment. 1. yes, the redirect which leads to an error is what follows POST request. I will edit the question. 2. OK, I will try. 3. I tried on local environment without reverse proxy, not reproduced. 4. I will edit the last sentence.

Comment: When I did https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=safari+get+cors+origin+problem I found some interesting info.. Did you investigate in general?

Comment: @Kukeltje Yes, I checked some articles about that, and I thought that issue is not related to the problem I have. Because, in this case, the request is not CORS request. All requests and reponses happen in the same domain. If it's not the point, please correct me.